# Is Magento Community and Enterprise are based on SaaS service?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community

I'm a new bie for the e-commerce platform. Actually I'm on the R&D stage to choose that which platform can be adopt to us. Therefore if you could reply me on the following it would be much appreciated?

1) Is Magento community and Enterprise edition based on SaaS service? I know MagentoGo is Saas but is two editions are SaaS?

2) Also I found the following link http://saas.smartosc.com/magento-saas/why-saas/ . Do you think as Web development company we should choose for this? or is this purely for typical customers?

3) Can we purchase enterprise extensions for the Magento Community version

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should research some more. I think you have a complete wrong idea about Magento and that might lead you to a bad decision you will regret after spending a lot of time and money.

Magento CE and EE are not SaaS and Magento Go is (going to be) closed.

About extensions for CE and EE, most of them work for both versions, but prior purchasing anything check if it is compatible with the version you previously choosed.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's was very helpful. However as I mentioned in my post I'm still on R&D stage, I've not yet decided which one to choose.